# Assigning value to a cell from another cell in another sheet - Pandas/Openpyxl/Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to work with an excel sheet. I need to assign a value to a cell from a cell in antoher sheet.

```
wb.active = 2
Results = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Results')
Results['A3'] = 'Weekly Average Spend'
Results['A4'] = 'Cost Per Trip'
Results['A5'] = 'Average Trips Per Week'
Results['A6'] = 'Total Spend'
wb.save("Test.xlsx")

sumPiv = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sumPiv')

Results['B3'] = sumPiv['B2'].value
```

Basically the 'B2' value in 'sumPiv'sheet needs to be assigned to 'B3' in 'Results' sheet. both of these sheets are in the same workbook/same excel file. but for some reason I dont see the value in the excel file after running the code.

Comment: You seem to be assigning `Results['B3']` **after** saving the workbook

Comment: I save the workbook again at the bottom. so thats not the problem

Comment: Provide a [mcve]